# Intenet in BroadcastReceiver in null in Android 8

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have working code to start schedule task for n seconds using `AlarmManager` and `BrodcastReceiver`

When I call `SetAlarm` after `delayTimeInMs` seconds  method I need to receive new notification from `BrodcastReceiver`

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context, int delayTimeInMs){

    AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    intent.putExtra("name", name);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + delayTimeInMs, pi);
}
```

Here is `BrodcastReceiver` class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
       showNotification(name);
   }
}
```

Here is manifest declaration

```
        <receiver android:name="com.flexsolution.faketextmessage.AlarmReceiver" />
```

`SetAlarm` method works fine `BrodcastReceiver` get called after X seconds, but my problem is on Android 8 (oreo)  `onReceive`  `name` is null I try with dummy string even int and still I get `null`

Can tell me why this isn't work ? And please suggest me working code of my example.

Thanks

Comment: send notification....like a push notification?

Comment: yes but that isn't problem, problem is that I onReseive get null in intent param

Comment: is it sending null?

Answer (score 0):

Android O changed the way they handle Service calls and Broadcasts. You can NOT use `AlarmManager` for this anymore. Sucks, I know, but I personally think its better.

Going forward, for Android <=> O you will have to use a `JobScheduler`.

Here is a great example of it.

https://blog.klinkerapps.com/android-o-background-services/